# CSS 3.0 Overflow-wrap and Word-wrap

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I need a word-wrap in my css, and at once I got this error:

`Validation (CSS 3.0): 'word-wrap' is not a known CSS property name.`

After some research I found out that the word-wrap was replaced with overflow-wrap.

When I use that one I get:

`Validation (CSS 3.0): 'overflow-wrap' is not a known CSS property name.`

I have the CSS 3.0 Intellisense installed.

Anyone got a clue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where did you get that errors ? Did you page site works with your browsers or not ?

Comment: Actually it's a warning in the Error list below my Visual Studio Application. My site works good but I need to use this in the .css file to break-word.

Answer (score 0):

According to CSS Text Module Level 3 (CSS3 Text), [`overflow-wrap`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#overflow-wrap) is a defined property, and `word-wrap` should be accepted as a synonym for it for legacy reasons. It’s still just a Working Draft, as most of CSS3 is, so a checker that purports to validate against CSS3 might reject or accept it – there is no formal definition for validating against something that is just a collection of documents of very varying maturity levels.

On the practical side, this property should almost never be used for texts in a language written in Latin letters, since it means that w ords ar e arbitr arily b roken wit hout in dicati ng the br eaks in any w ay. To find a solution to the problem that this property was supposed to solve, you need to formulate that question in a sufficiently concrete manner.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry it's not your fault. word-wrap is a valid CSS property. Check out this page:

http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-reference/css-word-wrap-property.php

So when check you CSS in W3C validation service it doesn't give you error.